# Android: center Textview in extended Layout

Tags: android, layout, view, gravity, layoutparams

Can I somehow prevent calling the Layout method of all Children if I only want to set the layout for the parent view and still want to keep the layout settings of the children?

Currently I call parent.layout() and all its children get a width and heiht of zero. Can't I somehow set the children to FillParent istead of setting the layout to ALL ? :-(

By the way, my parent is an extended LinearLayout containing mostly Textviews.

**Edit:**
Some code:

myLayout extends LinearLayout

```
myLayout.layout(left, top, right, bottom);                
myLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));

for each child in myLayout do {
  child.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  if (v instanceof TextView) {
    ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  }
```

But child still has:
left: 0 top: 0 right: 0 bottom: 0

**Edit 2:**
By the way: the code above is insider the onLayout method of a ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child views aren't getting measured (since you don't call their layout()), so the system still thinks that they are 0x0px.

Android uses a 2-pass system of measure/layout.

Check out the developer docs to see how the drawing/layout sequence happens: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

You might want to try calling their `layout()`, then setting the height/width on the children, then calling `requestLayout()`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height of children in `onLayout()` method of your extended LinearLayout. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        // set width of every child to FILL_PARENT, and height to WRAP_CONTENT
        child.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

I don't know why `setGravity()` doesn't work for you. May be you set gravity not for child but for layout? I can set gravity, e.g. in `onLayout()`:

```
if (child instanceof TextView) {
    ((TextView) child).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. child still remains at left: 0 top: 0 right: 0 bottom: 0